# JavaScript Scoping Idiosyncrancies

Tags: scoping

I'm new to JS (I'm more familiar with Java), so the scoping has been rather confusing for me. I was given the following code snippet, and I'm hoping someone can walk me through why the console.log() function calls are returning the values they're returning:

```
var x = 0;
function a (){
    var x = 1;

    function b(){
        console.log(x); //---> this will be undefined
        var x = 2;
        console.log(x); //---> this will be 2
    }

    b();

}

console.log(x);//---> this will be 0;
a();
```

Comment: What do you find confusing?

Comment: Remember that declaraction and definition of variables are two separate things. In JavaScript, declarations are hoisted to the beginning of the scope. Hence, they are visible but literally `undefined` before they are "lexically" declared. When you assign a value (other than `undefined`) to the variable then it becomes defined. That's all that there is to it.

Comment: Ok...let me think about how to phrase my confusion. I'm confused about what the specific scoping is for each variable declaration. So var x = 0 is considered a global declaration, but what about the variable declarations within the functions? I know that JS doesn't have block scope (so variables defined within a block are either local to the function they're defined in or global to the script if not defined within a function), but I was under the impression that variable declarations within functions are local to the function.

Comment: So, what's happening here that the console.log(x) function call at the end of the script is outputting 0 because it cannot access the variable declarations within the function, correct? And within b(), despite the fact that b() is defined and called within a(), it still doesn't have access to the variable declared within a(), correct? But if a() had had parameters, b() would have had access due to closure, correct?

Comment: But I guess I don't understand the hoisting that's happening within b()...is b() equivalent to 
function b(){
var x =2; //hoisted but undefined
console.log(x); //undefiend
var x = 2;
console.log(x); // 2
}